# using TS\ES6 getters for accessing deep properties (like shortcut)

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, getter

Is it fine to use getters for accessign deep properties of a class property? Or there's a more delicate way to do this?

Example:

```
const myObject = {
  very: {
    deeply: {
      nested: {
        property: {
          with: {
            a: {
              long: {
                name: "hello world"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

class Sample {
  constructor(private myObj) {}

  get name(): string {
    return this.myObj.very.deeply.nested.property.with.a.long.name;
  }
}
```

Repo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/tses6-getters-as-a-shortcut-for-deep-object-properties-h6rgr

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ if it works for you, go for it. There isn't a great sin committed in this code or anything. Sometimes you end up with deeply nested objects and having a shortcut is OK.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to know more. For example maybe there's already some existing "best practices" regarding this case or maybe, for example, some large companies like Google already have provided some guidelines. But currently I didn't find anything meaningful about this in the web .

Comment: Again ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ best practice is to probably not have deeply nested objects. But that's not always available. You can either add a getter (if that works for you) or if you don't want to/cannot change the object, might use some sort of utility function that fetches a property from path. Lodash has [`_.get()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#get) while Ramda has lenses (see [`lens()`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lens) or [`lensPath()`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lensPath) for example) which you can compose with [`view()`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#view). But there is no "standard" way of handling this.

Comment: Depends on how you use it. If you'd only write `return new Sample(myObject).name`, I would recommend to avoid a `class` and just have a function you can call like `return getName(myObject)`. Only if you reuse the `Sample` instance multiple times, or it has many more methods, it would make sense to use `class` here.

Comment: @flm, getter is just calling a function of an object without parenthesis, And if it return any object, It actually return its reference... But reading a prop of an deep object is different think, nothing to do with , getter.

Comment: @Bergi It's just an example. The implication is that this is a large class extending other class (e.g. Angular component), and there's a lot of nested objects inside.
You look at the question very literally :)

Comment: @flm I can't make assumptions about the things that are not part of the question. If you want more useful answers, please share your actual code. Another advice would be to avoid having/accessing such deeply nested properties in the first place, but again that depends on the real use case.

Comment: @Bergi Strange, I thought a good developer could make assumptions about different situations based on his experience.

Comment: @flm Yes, but we don't know your situation properly so I made the wrong assumption. And I'm not going to generalise my experience for all possible situations here, that's material for a blog post not for Q&A format which requires a clear question on a specific situation.

Comment: @flm "*I thought a good developer could make assumptions about different situations based on his experience*" they could but a *good* developer will avoid it. Because they likely have enough experience with enough drastically different things to understand that any assumption they make can lead them down the wrong path. We can only make reasonable assumptions if the unknown things are relatively small. You're asking us to pull out a crystal ball.